# How to bypass "numeric value out of range" when inserting into MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-insert

Sometimes I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column
```

I would like to know if is possible config MariaDB to accept and cut value when it is bigger than length column or if I need to do this check before insert data.

Comment: The question is why would you want the DB to destroy your data?

Comment: This error message is usually a sign that you have used an incorrect column type in your table. For example you tried to store a phone number in int, or a number bigger than 2147483647 as int and not bigint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MariaDB you would need to disable `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`, as explained in [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/):

> A mode where at least one of `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` or `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` is enabled is called strict mode.
>
> [...]
>
> With strict mode not set (default in version <= MariaDB 10.2.3), MariaDB will automatically adjust invalid values, for example, truncating strings that are too long, or adjusting numeric values that are out of range, and produce a warning.

Answer (score 0):

While GMB addresses the *state* Question, I want to make a suggestion about loading 'unknown' data.

1. `LOAD` into a temp table with excessively large datatypes.
2. Investigate the data with things like `SELECT MAX(x) ...`
3. Make informed decisions on the desired datatypes.
4. `CREATE TABLE`
5. `INSERT INTO real_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;`